# A simple JavaScript mad lib game

Tags: javascript

I've written a simple mad lib programme in JavaScript. All of its working except one thing. My name value is showing undefined. The code is below. Please help me to find out the error.

And here is [codepen](http://codepen.io/Minhazul-Islam/pen/oxrbbO?editors=1010) link.

HTML:

```
Name: <input type="text" id="name">
Favourite Color: <input type="text" name="color" id="color">
Fovourite Place: <input type="text" name="place" id="place">
Number: <input type="number" name="number" id="number">
<button id="launch">Launch</button>
<div id="story"></div>
```

Js:

```
var name = document.querySelector("#name");
var color = document.querySelector("#color");
var place = document.querySelector("#place");
var number = document.querySelector("#number");
var story = document.querySelector("#story")
var launch = document.querySelector("#launch");
launch.addEventListener("click", writeStory, false);

function writeStory(){
var launchedStory = "";
launchedStory += "<p>Welcome, " + name.value + ". ";
launchedStory += "Only silly people choose " + color.value + " as their favorite color.</p>";
launchedStory += "<p>Is " + place.value + " your current place or your birth place.</p>";
launchedStory += "<p>By the way, " + number.value + " is your serial number.</p>";

story.innerHTML = launchedStory;
}
```

Comment: Working fine for me in Chrome. Not in your codepen tho, but here: https://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/ued2rebb/

Comment: Also make sure this is run after the html has rendered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your code inside script tag in windows event onload function. The global variable name is conflicting with window object's name property. You can also change the name of global variable from name to something else.

Sol 1.

```
var nameElement = document.querySelector("#name");
```

Then you can read its value using `nameElement.value`

But it is good to not pollute the global namespace. So write your code in function scope.

Sol 2.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function () {
    // your code here
  }
</script>
```

Here is fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mrk_m/L1an24ut/1/

Comment: Not the problem. The code is after the tags. Also see my comment on the question. Your wrapping in a function moves the name from global scope

Comment: @mplungjan Modified answer to justify your comment. I didn't see the script tag was at the bottom.

Comment: Your answer is now complete, but the name part was already answered by @haim770

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the variable name from `name` to something else because the interpreter is resolving it as `window.name` instead.

Comment: Hi haim770, Thank you for your effective reply. But I want to know, Is interpreter taking `.name` from `name` attribute of `input` tag?

Comment: Well spotted... `var name` outside any function will be blocked by the `window.name` global var. Inside a function it would work

Comment: @Minhaz, It's not about the `name` attribute of the element but rather about the global context. In the browser, the global context is the `window` object that happened to have a `name` property as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's been answered above but in a more complex way. Simply put, "name" is a JavaScript keyword and shouldn't be used as a variable. I changed the id of "name" to "nombre", and it worked just fine.

https://codepen.io/SuperSchooler/pen/qeVqOj

HTML:

```
Name: <input type="text" id="nombre">
Favourite Color: <input type="text" name="color" id="color">
Favourite Place: <input type="text" name="place" id="place">
Number: <input type="number" name="number" id="number">
<button id="launch">Launch</button>
<div id="story"></div>
```

JS:

```
var name = document.querySelector("#nombre");
var color = document.querySelector("#color");
var place = document.querySelector("#place");
var number = document.querySelector("#number");
var story = document.querySelector("#story")
var launch = document.querySelector("#launch");
launch.addEventListener("click", writeStory, false);

function writeStory(){
    var launchedStory = "";
    launchedStory += "<p>Welcome, " + nombre.value + ". ";
    launchedStory += "Only silly people choose " + color.value + " as their favorite color.</p>";
    launchedStory += "<p>Is " + place.value + " your current place or your birth place.</p>";
    launchedStory += "<p>By the way, " + number.value + " is your serial number.</p>";

    story.innerHTML = launchedStory;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are doing `madlibs`, then do:

```
puts "give me a transportation"
transportation = gets.chomp
```

Then,

```
puts "then we got in the {transportation} and went to Wendy's"
```

Comment: But all on different lines!

Comment: It's helpful to use the code syntax (try selecting the lines you want as code and hitting `CTRL + K`  when writing code snippets). I don't know if your answer really relates to their question as to why the name wasn't working!